# How to assert that a backend endpoint has been called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm building an E2E test of an Angular application using Protractor. The backend HTTP services are being mocked with `$httpBackend`. So far, the test looks like this:

```
describe('foo', function () {
  it('bar', function () {
    var backendMockModule = function () {
      angular
        .module('backendMock', [])
        .run(['$httpBackend', function ($httpBackend) {
          $httpBackend.whenPUT('http://localhost:8080/services/foo/bar')
            .respond(function (method, url, data, header) {
              return [200, {}, {}];
            });
        }]);
    };
    browser.addMockModule('backendMock', backendMockModule);

    browser.get('http://localhost:8001/#/foo/bar');

    element(by.id('baz')).click();

    // here I would like to assert that the Angular app issued a PUT to '/foo/bar' with data = {...}
  });
});
```

The test is a little more elaborated than this, it tests for optimistic update of the interface and other stuff. But I think this is not relevant to the this question, so I removed the other parts. The test in itself is working fine, I'm able to check that the elements on the interface are as expected. What I didn't find out is:

**How to assert that the backend HTTP endpoint has been called with the correct data, method, headers, etc?**

I have tried to do it like this (adding `hasBeenCalled` variable):

```
describe('foo', function () {
  it('bar', function () {
    var hasBeenCalled = false;

    var backendMockModule = function () {
      angular
        .module('backendMock', [])
        .run(['$httpBackend', function ($httpBackend) {
          $httpBackend.whenPUT('http://localhost:8080/services/foo/bar')
            .respond(function (method, url, data, header) {
              hasBeenCalled = true;
              return [200, {}, {}];
            });
        }]);
    };
    browser.addMockModule('backendMock', backendMockModule);

    browser.get('http://localhost:8001/#/foo/bar');

    element(by.id('baz')).click();

    expect(hasBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But it does not work. I don't know exactly how the Protractor does the testing, but I imagine that it sends a serialized version of the function to the browser in the call `addMockModule` instead of running the test in the same process as the web page and so I'm not able to share state between the test and the browser (side question: is that correct?).

Answer (score 0):

`$httpBackend.flush()` is needed before expect(...)...